# Error plotting in a second series in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a scatter plot with two different series:

```
Ej4 = read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\Ulia\\Downloads\\Parte 5.xlsx", sheet = 4)
fix(Ej4)

graf = ggplot(Ej4, aes(x1,x1)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.8)
graf

variable = data.frame(y = c(6,9,6,17,12), y2= c(6,9,6,17,12))
variable

grafica2 = graf + geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = variable, colour ="blue")
grafica2
```

But R shows this error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found

There's no problem plotting graf, but I can't understand why R tells me there's is an error with grafica2

PD: Ej4 is a dataframe with numerical variables, with the exactly same size as 'variable'

Answer (score 0):

There's another way:

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data = Ej4, aes(x1,y1)) + geom_point(data = variable, aes(y,y2))
```